# Django Server Run Permanent

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I have an Django-React Project. I use React project build file in my Django project to run project together.
When ı use;

```
 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

command in my cloud linux server there is no any problem. My projects works well.
I want to run my project permanent. I use screen and;

```
screen -d -m python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

command. It works without any problem but after a certain time the project stops working.
Is there any opinion to run my project permanetly without any problem like run server command. I also use django channel to send data which calculated from django backend to react frontend.

Comment: You can use multiple terminal tabs or You can use tmux.

Comment: You should never use runserver command in production. runserver is only for local use. Use proper way to deploy it in cloud. setup servers like nginx or apache etc for production. Refer this - https://build.vsupalov.com/django-runserver-in-production/

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [link](https://tonyteaches.tech/django-nginx-uwsgi-tutorial/) and set up your server locally.
In this link after installing django don't create django project instead put your project and for settings file don't add domain name leave it blank or put localhost or 127.0.0.1 . When running in browser put localhost or localhsot ip. And change port to a different port to avoid conflict with other projects.
I think this will work for you.